# TYPO3 constants and condition in typoscript

Tags: typo3, constants, typo3-8.7.x

I have `constants.ts` file where all my constants are defined. There is also simple boolean checkbox:

```
plugin.mycustompage {
  top_header {
    # cat=mycustompage.top_header/privateNumberShow/010; type=boolean; label=Private - show phone number: boolean true or false
    privateNumberShow = 1
    # cat=mycustompage.top_header/privatePhoneNumber/010; type=string; label=Private - phone number
    privatePhoneNumber = 11223344
  }
}
```

Beside that, there is simple file in `lib/contactinfo.ts` file in which I would like to show / hide some `TEXT` based on `privateNumberShow` constant value. If the checkbox isn't checked then clear the value otherwise show it. Here is current code:

```
[globalVar = LIT:0 = {$plugin.mycustompage.top_header.privateNumberShow}]
  lib.contactInfo.20 >
[END]
```

That doesn't work. Also tried with that one which also doesn't work:

```
[$plugin.mycustompage.top_header.privateNumberShow = 0]
  lib.contactInfo.20 >
[END]
```

Using TYPO3 8.7.12. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch around your condition and ask for `LIT:1`. This way the TypoScript parser doesn't need to parse your contactInfo when your constant isn't 1 and this will benefit your performance.

```
[globalVar = LIT:1 = {$plugin.mycustompage.top_header.privateNumberShow}]
lib.contactInfo.20 = TEXT
lib.contactInfo.20{
    value = 123456789
}
[global]
```

Comment: Weird, but it actually works like a charm! Thanks :)